# Location services enabled but not working

Tags: gnome, firefox, location, geolocation, gnome-maps

I have location services enabled, however, when I use an app that requires location access such as gnome-maps or Firefox (with allowed permissions for google maps) it doesn't work. Google maps shows that there was an error while determining location and Gnome Maps shows a completely off location. Also the settings page shows no apps have requested location services.

[Image of the settings page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tatSw.png)

How do I fix this?

Edit: I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and I'm not sure when this issue has started occurring. I did not change anything in my system that would affect this.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It may be helpful to edit your question and provide some more details, such as what version of Ubuntu are you using, have you always had this issue, and what have you tried so far.

Comment: were you able to solve this? i am encountering the same error on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS as well.

Answer (score 1):

For me the location service works only when I switch it OFF. When I switch it ON, it stops working. I do not know why this is the case, maybe you can try it yourself with location services switched off.